# Webcam video streaming within local are network connection

Tags: ftp, streaming, video-streaming, live

My programming knowledge is limited, my question is " is there any way to stream Mpeg 4 files within local network but with client on my computer running windows and host on android smart phone or windows phone?". Is it is possible, which editor or IDE can I use to create this application?

Comment: Your scope is way too large. Programming is breaking down large problems into small problems, then solving them. You must start smaller. Have you tried to simply play a video in a web page yet?

Comment: To answer your question, yes it is possible, and any editor/IDE will be fine.